# Is there any cross-platform GUI framework that support data binding like in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, data-binding, cross-platform

Recently I'm working on a game project, and we need to develop some editors for designers to use. While other programmers are all working on Windows, I'm working on Mac OS X. I'm familiar with WPF and Windows Forms development and I'm looking for some GUI frameworks that support data bindings similar to WPF or Windows Forms development.

The GUI framework should satisfy these:

- Cross platform
- Support data bindings to object (like WPF or Windows Forms)
- It's best that it support XML serialization because XML is our data format

By the way, I don't care about the programming language, GUI frameworks based on any programming language are all welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight runs on MacOS.

It also runs out of browser so you can create an application that doesn't require the browser to be run and hence looks like a regular desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platforms that you want to support, but you could have a look at Moonlight the mono port of silverlight. Have a look at the alternative section of this page:
http://www.mono-project.com/WPF

Answer (score 0):

Knockout.js is said to be good. My colleagues prefer it over Wpf and Silverlight bindings. For instance if you have a fullname prop, which is a result of firstname and lastname, you have to hassle in Wpf with propertychanged, in Knockout.js you define it observable and the runtime makes it correctly notify its observers. It also supports validation.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't have data binding like WPF or Windows Forms, [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com) does works wonderfully for creating cross-platform applications. And XML is supported, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaFx, it supports binding better than Java Swing.  Also styling is based on CSS instead of Microsoft proprietary style logic.

Both WPF and JavaFX will target the GPU for extra fast rendering; they are comparable and competitor technologies.  But JavaFX is cross platform and less likely to be abandoned given Microsoft's track record.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html

Also, other answers here say Silverlight but Microsoft has abandoned this.